# Thymeleaf style attribute

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am working with thymleaf and I am trying to apply style directly from a spring object. I am trying to use the th:style attribute and pass in the value directly from the pojo.

I found this code online that works

```
th:style="${color == 'yellow' ? 'background:yellow' : 'background:blue'}"
```

But I want to pass in the value direct from the object.

Like this

```
th:style="${color == 'yellow' ? 'background:${color}' : 'background:blue'}"
```

or like this directly

```
th:style="background:${color}"
```

both ways throw up errors.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Another resource which may be useful: [String concatenation with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/01/11/string-concatenation-with-thymeleaf/)

Answer (score 3):

The [Thymeleaf docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#standard-expression-syntax) have many examples of String concatenation...  the easiest in this case would be [literal substitution](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions).

```
th:style="|background: ${color}|"
```

but you can just use a regular string concatenation as well.

```
th:style="${'background: ' + color}"
```

Comment: Thank you. Will have to go over the docs again i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `th:class="${color == 'yellow' ? 'yellowClass' : 'blueClass'}"`
And style to both class.
If you already have class attr, you can using `th:classappend`

Comment: I am still in prototyping phase so some of the styles are inline because it was quicker to do for testing. I wil be creating separate class for each style when I start developing.